# Lap time data uploaded from my Apple Watch doesn't match the lap times listed on my iPhone

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos, health.app

I uploaded my health data from my Apple Watch to keep track of my lap times.       But the lap times recorded in the XML file that I uploaded are consistently shorter than the ones listed on my watch.

For example, here's what I uploaded for one lap.

```
        date: '2020-02-04 18:54:54 -0800'
    duration: '0.5025173644224803'
durationUnit: 'min'
        type: 'HKWorkoutEventTypeLap'
```

but the actual lap time was more like 40 seconds.

Worse, the error ratio isn't constant, so that my uploaded lap time data really has no correlation with my actual data. This is very strange because the duration, kilocals, etc for the entire workout are exactly correct.    Could anybody advise please?